# Looking for a way to have all functions send output to another function

Tags: powershell

I realize the title is a little confusing but I couldn't figure out a better way to phrase it.

I have a Powershell script with a couple dozen functions.  Currently, I have the exact same code in every function to format the output.  Here's a snippet:

```
function function1 () {
    do something...
    output code here
}

function function2 () {
    do something...
    output code here
}
```

The output code is exactly the same.  Being a fan of code deduplication, this is driving me crazy because every time I add a new function I have this template code that I have to apply.  I've tried putting the entire script in a try/catch block and throwing the object that is output but I couldn't get it to work and this still requires coding in the same throw statement in every function.

Does anyone know of something I can do to have all of these functions in this script to automatically send their output to another function or am I just going to have to live with this?

Comment: What kind of output formatting are you doing and how are you outputting them?  Are these objects all the same type? Maybe a proxy function for whatever out-* or write-* you're using that would implement the custom formatting for objects of that type?

Comment: The functions are just outputting an ordered hash table with a few elements.  They are all the same type.

Comment: If it's related to the other thread, the idea was that the hash table just gets passed from test to test as-is.  Each test adds a little more to it.  At the end of all the tests, you pipe that to the New-TestResult fuction and it returns an object built from the hash table.

Comment: It would be easier, IMHO, to just add a test for an "Aborted" property. If a critical test fails have it add that property with it's name as the value. Have all the tests just check for that property and if it's there add their entry with a value of "Skipped" and send it on down the pipe. Don't worry about formatting until the end of the chain.

Comment: What if I'd like to use these function as one-offs?  For example, I want my Test-Wmi function to be in the big health check but I also want to do some ad hoc Test-WMi checks as well.

Comment: You could add some switch parameters to the test-wmi function for selective testing, and make the default to run all tests.

Answer (score 2):

If the functions have no parameters, you can use this simple solution:

```
function addOutputCode {
    param($name)
    $oldBody = (get-item function:$name).ScriptBlock
    $newBody = {
        param($computer) 
        $funcOutput = . $oldBody $computer
        # some formatting
        $funcOutput | % { 'FORMATTED: ' + $_ }
    }.GetNewClosure()
    Set-Item function:$name -value $newBody
}
```

As you can see the functions gets the body of the function and assignes new body with formatting code. You can try it, just copy & paste the code below.

```
# this is your file with defined functions
function f1 { param($c) 'this is test of ' + $c }
function f2 { $c.Length; 'this was length of $c' }
# now f1 and f2 would return unformatted data
# f1 
# f2

# add formatting code
addOutputCode f1
addOutputCode f2
# now if you call f1 or f2, they return formatted data
# f1 comp1
# f2 comp2
```

Comment: The functions all have one parameter.  They are PC checks that I'm running against many PCs to check for stuff like services started, files existing, etc.